# Equicontinuity of $\{f^n\}$ for a continuous $f:X\rightarrow X$

Tags: metric-spaces, equicontinuity

I came across this while trying to do a problem frm ergodic theory. Let $X$ be a compact metric space, and let $f:X\rightarrow X$ be a continuous function. Can we say anything about the equicontinuity of $\{f^n\}_{n=1}^\infty$? ($f^n$ is the composition of $f$ with itself $n$ times).

I thought about showing that $\{f^n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ has compact closure, using a diagonal argument to extract  (from a subsequence) another subsequence which converges pointwise on a countable dense set. However, I then got stuck. I also tried looking for a counterexample (I have no idea if the proposed result actually holds), but came up empty-handed.

Comment: I think we can say something if $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{d(f(x_n),f(x))}{d(x_n,x)}$  exists at every $x \in X$

Comment: Let $\delta_x(\varepsilon)$ be a modulus of continuity of $f$ at a point $x$, then it is enough to show that $\delta_x^n(\varepsilon)$ does not go to zero as $n \to \infty$ at fixed $x,\varepsilon$, where the exponent again denotes composition. One way for this to happen is for $f$ to be Lipschitz with a Lipschitz constant of at most $1$, since in this case you can have $\delta_x(\varepsilon)=\varepsilon/L$. In the situation of ergodicity, however, you gain some benefit, because there's some $n_0$ with $f^{n_0}(x)$ close to $x$, which makes things much better.

Comment: For example, if $X=[-1,1],f(x)=\begin{cases} 2x & x \in [-1/2,1/2] \\ -1 & x \in [-1,-1/2] \\ 1 & x \in [1/2,1] \end{cases}$ then the criterion I wrote is violated but I think you are still nevertheless in good shape, because the iteration moves you away from the "bad area" to the "good area".

Comment: Thus I think unless the criterion I wrote holds, there will necessarily be some subtle geometric issues to consider...(Also, writing it in that simplified form I actually already assumed $\delta$ is just a uniform modulus of continuity, not a pointwise one. But that's OK, because there always is one of those, since $X$ is compact.)

Comment: In the case where $X$ is the Riemann sphere and $f$ is a rational function, the set where the iterates are equicontinuous is the Fatou set, and its complement is the Julia set of $f$. This way you get lots of examples with quite complicated behavior. You are correct that one can find subsequential limits on the set where the iterates are equicontinuous, using Arzela-Ascoli.

Comment: @Ian Could you elaborate on your comment regarding ergodicity? How do you know that there's some $n_0$ with $f^{n_0}(x)$ close to $x$? And do you mean arbitrarily close?

Comment: Since $X$ is compact, the collection of iterates $\{f^n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is equicontinuous on $X$ if and only if there is a subsequence that converges uniformly on $X$ which in general won't always exist.

Comment: @MattAPelto Yes, that's essentially Arzelà-Ascoli, but do you have a counterexample?

Comment: $P(z)=z^2$ on the boundary of the unit disk in $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: You might want to consider a different tone next time you see me posting, it might net you a better counterexample or whatever. For the record, you are obviously welcome for this frankly easy to see counterexample.

Comment: @MattAPelto I'm sorry you got the impression I was using a bad tone, it certainly wasn't my intention. That being said, I'm not sure being condescending is the best way to go here.

Comment: Well this is the math forum, so the reasons I rarely post on here disagree.

Comment: @MattAPelto Um, okay? I'm going to assume you're having a bad day. Thank you for your counterexample, I hope your day gets better!

Answer (score 0):

The following is true:

If $(X,T)$ is distal, then $\{T^n\}$ is equicontinuous it'd there exists an equivalent metric on $X$ making it an isometry. The skew product on $\mathbb{T}^2$ given by

$(x,y) \mapsto (x+\alpha,y+x)$

Is distal but cannot be made into an isometry